# Angular routerLinkActive How to Set Link for a tag and its child tag i tag seperatly

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my html snippet. Trying to

GUI Rep:
[image]

Html Rep:

```
<li *ngFor="let objSubMenu of objMenu.menus" [hidden]="!objSubMenu.show">
                                
 <a class="button" routerLink="{{objSubMenu.url}}" routerLinkActive="activebutton">{{objSubMenu.name | translate }} 
   <i id="idMenuNewTabIcon" class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true" (click)="fnOnMenuNewTabIcinClick(objSubMenu.url)"></i></a></li>
```

Hirarchy is li -> a -> i

tag has set **routerLink** property and child tag  tag has set (click) event conncetd.
The problem is while accessing child tag, both click event and routerLink is working.

How to Set This in a way that both events works separately

ie: Clicking on Branch is working fine (routerLink). Clicking on icon is the problem both routerLink and onclick event is working.

So i am trying to find a way to prevent routerLink effect while clicking on icon.